# Oracle 11g: substitute record on Table A with latest record from Table B

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have 2 tables, Table A and Table B. I need to return all records from Table A, but I need COL_A replaced with latest value of COL_A from TABLE_B if the ID exist.

```
TABLE_A                       TABLE_B
ID COL_A                      A_ID   COL_A  CREATED_DATE
1  AAA                        1      AA1    1/11/18
2  BBB                        1      AA2    1/12/18
3  CCC                        3      CC1    1/12/18
```

Expected output:

```
ID COL_A
1  AA2
2  BBB
3  CC1
```

I'm able to execute the following with Oracle 12c, but not on 11g. Need help on how to query this for 11g?

```
select ID, 
NVL((select * from (select FIRST_VALUE(COL_A) OVER (ORDER BY CREATED_DATE DESC) from TABLE_B WHERE A_ID=A.ID) where ROWNUM=1),COL_A) AS COL_A
from TABLE_A A
```

Comment: I don't see an obvious join condition here.  Why did you structure your tables this way?

Comment: you can use `merge` statement

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How would you restructure them?

Comment: For starters, create clean join keys between the two tables, so you don't have employ SQL Olympics for what would otherwise be a fairly simple query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ok...so back to my original question, given my example, how you'd structure them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the join between 2 tables and a subquery to check for max date:

```
select a.ID, NVL(b.col_a, a.col_a) 
from TABLE_A a left outer join TABLE_B b 
on a.id = b.a_id 
and b.created_date = 
(select max(innerB.createdDate) from Table_B innerB where innerB.a_id = a.id);
```

Try this and let me know in case of error

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Comment: on a related note, I can't create a view out of this query. It says "ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery". Any ideas? thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to use window functions:

```
select a.id, coalesce(b.col_a, a.col_a) as col_a
from a left join
     (select b.*,
             row_number() over (partition by b.a_id order by b.created_date) as seqnum
      from b
     ) b
     on b.a_id = a.id and b.seqnum = 1;
```

This seems much simpler than a version that uses a `join` *and* a correlated subquery.